# Search box with button (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a search box with a button on it's side, like the this:

[image]

But just on the right side of the page. So I put **pull-right** and this is how my code like:

```
<form action="/hms/accommodations" method="GET">            
<div class="input-group pull-right">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch"/>
   <div class="input-group-btn pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
   </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

and when I tried to run it, this is how it looks like:

[image]

Why is does the alignment like that? I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Basically there is no need of pull-right class in input group

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove **pull-right** class from `<div class="input-group-btn pull-right">`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="/hms/accommodations" method="GET"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch"/>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: When I tried that, the search box become full size, I edit my question Sir.

Comment: The output is in full size Sir, it's not on the right side. I just remove the **pull-right**.

Comment: Just added **pull-right** in `<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-md-4">` and it's good. Thank you for your help Sir.

Comment: remove one col-md-4 :-P

Comment: I did Sir. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="search-box">
                         <input type="search" class="form-control ds-input" id="search-input"
                                placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" role="combobox"
                                aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-owns="algolia-autocomplete-listbox-0"
                                style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle;" dir="auto">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add ( float:left ) to form-control. i hope it will works.

Comment: I will add that in my bootstrap css? But when I do that when ever I use **form-control** it will be on the left side.